# Perform condition based addition using parallel streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a first method whose task is to basically calculate the sums of entries in the list of attributes based on conditions as. I am trying to achieve this using parallel streams(let say the list is huge). Although I am using atomic double here to handle race condition, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do so, since Java8 comes with many features inbuilt.

Code:

```
public double getSum(List<SomeObject> list, boolean flag1, boolean flag2){
    AtomicDouble sum = new AtomicDouble();
    list.parallelStream().forEach(item -> {
        if(flag1){
            sum.addAndGet(flag2 ? item.getFirstData() : item.getSecondData());
        } else {
            sum.addAndGet(flag2 ? item.getThirdData() :item.getFourthData());
        }
    });
    return sum.doubleValue();
}
```

For second method how do we do it:

```
enter code herepublic double getSum(Set<String> keys, HashMap<String, SomeObject> map, boolean flag1, boolean flag2){
    AtomicDouble sum = new AtomicDouble();

    keys.parallelStream().forEach(key -> {
        SomeObject item = map.get(key);
        if(flag1){
            sum.addAndGet(flag2 ? item.getFirstData() : item.getSecondData());
        } else {
            sum.addAndGet(flag2 ? item.getThirdData() :item.getFourthData());
        }
    });
    return sum.doubleValue();
}
```

Comment: `return list.parallelStream().mapToDouble(flag1? flag2? SomeObject::getFirstData: SomeObject::getSecondData: flag2? SomeObject::getThirdData: SomeObject::getFourthData) .sum()`

Comment: Thanks very much. I added one more scenario to calculate the sum.

Comment: @AndyTurner the code of my previous comment does already consider the unchanging nature of the `boolean` flags, i.e. passes an unconditional function to `mapToDouble`. @SomenBiswas for your second method, just insert `.map(map::get)` before the `mapToDouble` step.

Comment: @Holger indeed.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments and given the second version of the code, you could use the following convention. Create a `ToDoubleFunction` based on the conditional logic from `flag1` and `flag2` as follows :

```
boolean flag1, flag2; // provided as in your input
// create a ToDoubleFunction for conversion based on the above
ToDoubleFunction<SomeObject> chooseValue = new ToDoubleFunction<>() {
    @Override
    public double applyAsDouble(SomeObject value) {
        return flag1 ?
                flag2 ? value.getFirstData() : value.getSecondData() :
                flag2 ? value.getThirdData() : value.getFourthData();
    }
};
```

represented as:

```
ToDoubleFunction<SomeObject> chooseValue = value -> flag1 ?
        flag2 ? value.getFirstData() : value.getSecondData() :
        flag2 ? value.getThirdData() : value.getFourthData();
```

Thereafter using the same function in your existing code, you can update it as :

```
public double getSum(List<SomeObject> list) {
    return list.parallelStream()
            .mapToDouble(chooseValue)
            .sum();
}
```

and in your updated version as;

```
public double getSum(Set<String> keys, Map<String, SomeObject> map) {
    return keys.stream()
            .filter(map::containsKey)
            .map(map::get)
            .mapToDouble(chooseValue)
            .sum();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an anonymous inner class instead of a lambda expression? Note that the code of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771697/perform-condition-based-addition-using-parallel-streams#comment96323613_54771697) does not reevaluate `flag1` and `flag2` repeatedly, but creates an unconditional function doing the operation indicated by `flag1` and `flag2`.

Comment: @Holger anonymous class - for ease of understanding(detailing)... sorry, didn't get the part about the *unconditional function* you're trying to convey.

Comment: Your function will evaluate `flag1` and `flag2` each time, `applyAsDouble` is called, to decide again, which actual method to invoke. In contrast, code of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771697/perform-condition-based-addition-using-parallel-streams#comment96323613_54771697) will evaluate these flags only once when the `ToDoubleFunction` is instantiated and provide a function which will invoke the right function directly, without evaluating the flags again.

Answer (score 0):

The flags are passed to the method once, and their values don't change during its execution, so there's no need to evaluate them for each item. Additionally, using an `AtomicDouble` seems redundant. You should only map the item to a `double` and let the stream sum them:

```
public double getSum(List<SomeObject> list, boolean flag1, boolean flag2){
    ToDoubleFunction<SomeObject> mapper;
    if (flag1) {
        if (flag2) {
            mapper = SomeObject::getFirstData;
        } else {
            mapper = SomeObject::getSecondData;
        }
    } else {
        if (flag2) {
            mapper = SomeObject::getThirdData;
        } else {
            mapper = SomeObject::getFourthData;
        }
    }
    return list.parallelStream().mapToDouble(mapper).sum();
}
```